# Pyspark error when i write to parquet table in hive

Tags: pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql, cloudera, hue

I created a hive table with this code :

```
CREATE TABLE rci_db_inventory.dev_cr_asset_trace_2 (   id STRING,   acn STRING,   source_max_date BIGINT,   col_name STRING,   source_value STRING,   type STRING,   lid STRING,   source_id STRING,   created_by STRING,   created_on STRING,   traceable STRING,   found STRING ) PARTITIONED BY (   ctl_eid STRING )  STORED AS PARQUET
```

So the problem is when i try to write in this table from a pyspark df, this is the code:

```
columnar_df.withColumn("found", lit(head_bi_name)).write.format("parquet").mode("append") \
                .partitionBy("ctl_eid").saveAsTable('rci_db_inventory.dev_cr_asset_trace_2')
```

The error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"The format of the existing table rci_db_inventory.dev_cr_asset_trace_2 is `HiveFileFormat`. It doesn't match the specified format `ParquetFileFormat`.;"
```

**I use a cloudera on premise cluster.**

Answer (score 1):

what if you try using .format('hive')?

```
columnar_df.withColumn("found", lit(head_bi_name)).write.format("hive").mode("append") \
               .partitionBy("ctl_eid").saveAsTable('rci_db_inventory.dev_cr_asset_trace_2')
```